# Displaying specific data in a header

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a small website that allows a user to browse some of Shakespeare plays. I have it working that when a user clicks on a play, the name of the play is displayed in a header and the script of the play is displayed within a separate div.

This is working fine but I am now trying to organise the various plays into a drop down menu. I have split the plays into two categories (comedies and histories) and have grouped the plays accordingly.

The problem I now have is that once I click on a play via the drop down menu, the entire list of plays within that catergory (i.e. comedies) is displayed in the header instead of only the play I have selected. The play I selected however is still correctly shown in the div that displays the play (the 'mainOutput' div).

So basically what i need to know is how to I can set up that drop down menu so that only the title of the play I select shows in the header. Hopefully I have explained this correctly and any help would be appreciated! here is my code...

The jquery that initiates the play to be shown:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   /* The code here can be modified to allow for any means of obtaining playName */
    $('li').click(function(event) {
  var playName = $(this).attr("id");
      $("header>span").text($(this).text());
      loadPlay(playName);
    });
```

The drop down menu:

```
<div style="margin-left:50px;">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Comedies</a>
            <ul id="help">
                <li>
                    <img class="corner_inset_left" alt="" src="corner_inset_left.png"/>
                    <li id="all_well.xml" class="comedy">All's Well That Ends Well</li>
                    <img class="corner_inset_right" alt="" src="corner_inset_right.png"/>
                </li>
                </ br>
                <li id="as_you.xml" class="comedy">As You Like It</li> </ br>
                <li id="com_err.xml" class="comedy">The Comedy of Errors</li> </ br>
              <li id="cymbelin.xml" class="comedy">Cymbeline</li> </ br>
              <li id="lll.xml" class="comedy">Love's Labours Lost</li> 
              <li id="m_for_m.xml" class="comedy">Measure for Measure</li> 
                          <li class="last">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Histories</a>
            <ul id="help">
                <li>
                    <img class="corner_inset_left" alt="" src="corner_inset_left.png"/>
                     <li id="hen_iv_1.xml" class="history">Henry IV, Part I</li>                                                                        <img class="corner_inset_right" alt="" src="corner_inset_right.png"/>
                </li>
          <li id="hen_iv_2.xml" class="history">Henry IV, Part II</li> 
          <li id="hen_v.xml" class="history">Henry V</li> 
          <li id="hen_vi_1.xml" class="history">Henry VI, Part I</li> 
          <li id="rich_iii.xml" class="history">Richard III</li>
                <li class="last">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </div>
```

Where the play data is displayed:

```
<header><span>Shakespeare's Plays<span></span></span></header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you bind `click` event to all `li` items, including your dropdown list headings. You can change the selector to make it workable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function(event) {
        var playName = $(this).attr("id");
        $("header > span").text($(this).text());
        loadPlay(playName);
    });
});
```

Of course, there are many other problems in your code.

1. You should improve IDs of the elements (e.g. you have several elements with ID `help`, should be only one).
2. List element `ul` should contain as first childs `li` elements only (you also have `br` elements, not correct).
3. Pay attention, you have two `span` elements in `header`. Consider using only one if you wish to fill it with text (see JavaScript).